# VueJS ~ Error al usar v-for dentro de un componente

Tags: html, vue.js

Estoy haciendo un componente llamado **slider** y tengo una función llamado, **listarNoticias**, lo que quiero es mostrar las noticias en el slider usando v-for. Pero me da el siguiente error

> [Vue warn]: Error compiling template:
>
> Cannot use v-for on stateful component root element because it renders
>   multiple elements.

app.js

```
Vue.component('slider', {

template: `     
    <div v-for="noticia in noticias" class="item-slider">
        <div class="container">
            <div class="row align-items-center">
                <div class="col-lg-7">
                    <div class="info-slider">
                        <h1> {{ title.rendered }} </h1>
                        <a href="#" class="btn-iw outline">Leer más <i class="fa fa-long-arrow-right"></i></a>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>  
`,
})


new Vue({
    el: '#layout',
    data() {
        return {
            noticias: []
        }
    },
    methods : {
        listarNoticias(){
            let me = this;
            var url= '.../wp-json/wp/v2/posts'; //quite la url, para la pregunta
            axios.get(url).then(function (response) {
                me.noticias = response.data;
            })
            .catch(function (error) {
                console.log(error);
            });
        },
    },
    mounted() {
        this.listarNoticias();
    },
})
```

En el index tengo lo siguiente

```
<div id="layout">
<slider></slider>
</div>

<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/vue@2.6.10/dist/vue.js"></script>
<script src="https://unpkg.com/axios/dist/axios.min.js"></script>
<script src="assets/js/app.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

El problema que tenes es que el primer div debe estar vacio.

Lo que pasa con vue, es que puede tener solo un elemento padre o principal por componente, y vos al poner el v-for sobre el div principal, le estarias pidiendo a vuel que repita ese div que es padre montones de veces.

Todo tu template se soluciona rodeando lo que ya tenes, dentro de otro `<div>` o `<template>`

```
template: ` 
    <div>    
        <div v-for="noticia in noticias" class="item-slider">
            <div class="container">
                <div class="row align-items-center">
                    <div class="col-lg-7">
                        <div class="info-slider">
                            <h1> {{ title.rendered }} </h1>
                            <a href="#" class="btn-iw outline">Leer más <i class="fa fa-long-arrow-right"></i></a>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>  
`,
})
```

Comment: Ahora me sale otro error: Property or method "noticias" is not defined on the instance but referenced during render.

Comment: Ese es un componente diferente. Noticias tiene que ser una prop